# Why this quad looks like that?

Tags: geometry, topology

I use auto smooth 30°, i tried 60° too but the problem doesn't dissapear
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you check for duplicated vertices along the edges that seem "discontinuous" ?

Comment: Check normal orientation, internal faces, A, M, B in Edit Mode to remove doubles, clear custom split normals

Comment: Yeah i already check for duplicates and normals, i don't really understand why this happens

Comment: Hello please share your object or at least a part of it: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=dXB99aPG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/dXB99aPG/)

Comment: The mesh is non-manifold, the problematic edges have 3 face-neighbors (in non-manifold mesh all edges have exactly 2 face-neighbors)

Comment: Oh, you know how to fix that?

Comment: It may be tricky to explain, basically you should create a surface without thickness, then **solidify** it. Notice how solidified faces don't have internal faces. That is, once you're *inside* the *"hull"*, you can visit every place of that hull, and no internal face stops you. That's the "correct" topology that makes the smooth shading work.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your help!

Comment: Resolved thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Markus says your topology is not good, you have inner faces, it makes the shading happen between the outer faces but also between the outer and the inner faces:

[image]

You should not have faces that are adjacent to more than one other face by one of its edges (image below). To fix that just remove these inner faces and if you need thickness extrude all the faces.

[image]